# Installing Python-based CMSes on a shared hosting?

Tags: python, django, content-management-system, hosting

I have two questions that I would be happy if you help me with:

1. Is it correct that if a shared hosting supports Django, then it supports Django-based 
   CMSes?
2. Let's say I have shell access to my shared hosting. Is it possible to install Django or any
   other Python-based CMS through SSH or should additional support be provided by the hosting
   company?

Comment: Not a programming question, so off-topic for StackOverflow. Try one of the sysadmin stack exchange sites.

Comment: @Spacedman Even if my first question is not directly related to computer programming, I believe my 2nd question is completely related to computare programming; Consider the case that the answer is affirmative then someone would come up with the instructions of doing such a thing!!And I don't deserve a minus vote!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requirements for the hosting to be sure you can use it for django are:

1. Recent 2.x version of python, it is obvious requirement, but I have experience with hosting that support only python 2.4 and support for this version is droped in django 1.4.
2. The only python libraries that you'll need are the ones requiring compilation, in most cases that will be PIL and the wrapper for the database (psycopg, mysql-python)
3. WSGI, FastCGI, SCGI or AJP support

Evrything else you can put in virtualenv (even the packages the hosting have already installed ). If the hosting don't have virtualenv you can copy the virtualenv.py file from the virtualenv source and create environment with it.

```
python virtualenv.py env
```

Comment: I don't understand why It is not possible to install compilation needed items in virtualenv?

Comment: Most hosting providers don't allow GCC, or at least once I worked with.

Answer (score 1):

We can't really answer the question because a particular shared hosting deal might have certain technical restrictions that prevent you from doing what you want. So it is best to check before purchasing shared hosting that claims to offer Python/Django support.

That having been said:

1. Most likely yes, if you're allowed to install additional packages then you can indeed install a Django-based CMS. A Django-based CMS requires Django, some additional configuration and one or more database tables but you should be able to install that when you have Django and a database up and running.
2. Possibly, it depends on whether you can configure [WSGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Server_Gateway_Interface) properly for Django. If you can't do that then you may need to rely on configuration support from your shared hosting company. If you are free to install software (such as Django), configure your Python packages and you also have a database available then you can indeed use Django or a different Python-based CMS.

Comment: So I could simply ask if I am able to install software. Am I right?

Comment: Plus, If I have access to easy_install would that be enough to consider that I will be able to install Django or any python based CMS?

Comment: @Naji No, do not just ask if you are able to install software.  Some (most?) shared hosting will let you install software but will not let you configure Apache to serve wsgi applications.  Just installing software isn't enough -- you have to be able to hook your application up to the existing Apache install.  In general, shared hosting does not support Django or other wsgi apps unless they specifically state it. Dreamhost is one shared hosting that does support it, although I would prefer a dedicated application host such as Heroku or a VPS from Linode etc. to them.